# Is this citation present in Kurma Purana?

Tags: puranas, kurma, quote

Somebody with the handle of jayatuvaishnavadharma at Quora says:

> The dvaitins quote a pramana from the kurma purANa to justify this as follows:

> > raxitaM naiva shaknoShi svAtmAnamapi shaN^kara | yuddhe kiM jeShyasi tvaM mAM pUrvavR^ittaM mayochyate || yadA madbhaktashakrasya yaj~nadhvamsaH kR^itastvayA | tadA.ahaM te shirashChitvA tatkratU raxito mayA | tato mAM prArthayAmAsa manobhIShTAya pArvatI | tadA vai matprasAdena prANAn.h lebhe bhavAn.h shiva ||

> > Meaning: (Vishnu says:) Hey Shankara, you are not capable of protecting even yourself. How can you win over me in a war? I shall recount an old account (pUrvavR^ittaM). You came to ruin the yajna performed by my devotee, Indra. Then, I protected that Yajna, having got your head severed. Then, to obtain you back, Parvati prayed to me; after which, you got your life due to my grace.

I don't see it in the Kurma Purana at internet archive.

Is it really there?

Comment: Most of the Puranas have undergone insertion & deletion of content throughout their existence. Due to lack of availability of books in large numbers, it wasn't impossible for anybody with a good knowledge of Sanskrit to claim any random passage to be present in xyz purana. Madhvas are renowned for inserting verses that demonize Adi Shankara and Advaita & deify Dvaita doctrine within the Puranas. The examples are to be found in Padma Purana & Garuda Purana. Unless a Pauranik verse has been cross-checked by a third-party, it can't be considered authentic.

Comment: No. Not in the extant text

Comment: How absurd making their own verses. Tomorrow i can also declare myself as Veda-Vyasa. Lol. ..